# Cannot access pfsense web GUI after installation on a remote server

Tags: pfsense

I have installed PfSense on a remote server, But now that installation is over I cannot access the webpage over servers public IP... (neither http nor https)
The only thing I have access to is console menu with its 16 options.
Is there anything I can do there to make web GUI accessible from wan public IP?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this, https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/firewall/remote-firewall-administration.html

Comment: Thanks, But all of these solutions require an initial access to web GUI, that I do not have...

Comment: This site is quite waste of time..., I ask a question, someone gives a pretty straight forward answer that could be found in first page of google search results, and then everything freezes for ever.......

Comment: Are you able to SSH to it? If so, you should be able to do a port forward tunnelled through the SSH connection to port 80/443 on the firewall.

Comment: You should also be able to disable the firewall via the cli (https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/usermanager/locked-out-of-the-webgui.html#remotely-circumvent-firewall-lockout-by-temporarily-changing-the-firewall-rules) and access the web gui while the firewall is disabled.